# Get missing package golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode import cycle

Tags: go, goimports

I'm trying to reproduce [this go issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39491), but can't easily build their example:

```
$ cat main.go
package main
import ("fmt"; "golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode")
func main() {
    res, err := unicode.UTF16(unicode.BigEndian, unicode.UseBOM).NewDecoder().String(" ")
    fmt.Println(res, err)
}
$ go mod init golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode
go: creating new go.mod: module golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode
go: to add module requirements and sums:
    go mod tidy
$ go mod tidy 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
$ go build main.go
package command-line-arguments
    imports golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode
    imports golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode: import cycle not allowed
```

Comment: Golang does not allow packages to import each other

Comment: @MargachChris where is the cycle? it's not in their minimal example

Comment: Your  module path is the problem: don't pick `golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
go mod init golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode
```

I suspect you should not initialise a project with a module name using the same name as your import.

Try:

```
go mod init test
```